# Word for when a problem goes away as soon as you have a solution?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when a problem goes away as soon as you have found a solution for it?

For example, I finally thought up a counterattack in a hypothetical game, but now none of my opponents are giving me the opportunity to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Dispel?  Moot?

My counterattack was immediately dispelled when my opponents stopped attacking a certain way.

My counterattacks were made moot once my opponents stopped attacking me a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

Moot is good or maybe superfluous?

Not directly related to your example, but some people say 'superseded by events' - meaning, no action needed or taken now because something happened to change everything.